# sass-rails helpers "image-url", "asset-url" are not working in rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline

I am on 3.2.1, with sass-rails-3.2.4 and sass-3.1.15...

The documentation for the asset pipeline says:

```
asset-url("rails.png", image) becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
image-url("rails.png") becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
```

...

So I made the following file:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/public/omg.css.sass

body
  background: asset-url('snake.gif', image)

#lol
  background: image-url('snake.gif')
```

and when I visit localhost:3000/assets/public/omg.css I get:

```
body {
  background: asset-url("snake.gif", image); }

#lol {
  background: image-url("snake.gif"); }
```

...  I also tried changing the file to omg.css.scss and changed the syntax to:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/public/omg.css.scss

body {
  background: asset-url('snake.gif', image);
}

#lol {
  background: image-url('snake.gif');
}
```

but get the same results...  does anyone have any idea why these helpers are not working?

Comment: My project has 2 stylesheets (one for the webpage & one for the app). I'm having this problem on one, but not on the other?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Despite what the documentation says, it seems the default options in rails 3.2.6 allow you to just make things work with even less path information in your CSS.
E.g. `../app/assets/images/rails.png` is references in your example.css.scss file with something like:

`background: white url(rails.png) repeat-y;`

You don't include the `image-url` or `asset-url` into your scss (as far as I know), just plain `url(your_image.png)`. That bit of documentation appears to be just an explanation of what it is doing in the background.

Comment: Using just `url(rails.png)` doesn't use the fingerprinted version of the asset file. In our .css.scss files, we needed to use `background: image_url('my-image.png')`.

Comment: If you need to get the fingerprinted output, make sure that you **don't** do this: `rake assets:precompile`. You need to have the production environment set, like this `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` otherwise it will just generate the assets links for development mode.

Comment: ^^ that comment doe!!!  Saved me HOURS of head ache 
`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Finally good answer: just use url(your_image.png). Thx @Jay H.

Comment: Convert css to scss may help and use @import in application.scss

Answer (score 11):

When I hit this problem, it was because I had not included the css file in the asset pipeline for pre-compilation. As a result, it would be generated at runtime. Because the sass-rails gem is commonly in the :assets group, the helpers are unavailable when generating css files at runtime.

Try adding the following line to your application.rb (or production.rb):

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( public/omg.css )
```

I found the fix on [this post](http://jalada.co.uk/2012/01/23/adding-files-to-config-assets-precompile-in-rails-3-1.html) including a gotcha around naming the files when adding them to the precompiler.

Answer (score 6):

If you have updated your app to Rails 3.1 in the past, make sure you changed your application.rb file from

```
# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

to

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

See [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) on upgrading to Rails 3.1 and adding the asset pipeline.

**Update:** Rails 4 goes back to the old way of doing it. Thanks *Aaron Gray*!

```
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

Comment: Once you go to Rails 4 though, you'll want to go back to the old way of using Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env). See http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4.

Answer (score 4):

Have you enabled the asset pipeline in `application.rb`?

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

You did right by setting the extension on your Sass stylesheets to `.css.scss`. That lets Rails know to parse the file with Sass first before it emits the content as CSS.

Comment: I created a similar file at a similar location and got the correct output. Do you have sass-rails in your Gemfile? Can you update your original post with the contents of `config/environments/development.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try clearing /tmp/cache.  I am too new to Rails and Sass to know why this worked, but it solved the same problem for me after hours of searching.

BTW, this worked despite the fact that I could see other Sass directives, such as setting variables and calculating with them, being executed.  I'm sure there is a very simple explanation, once I have time to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

I made the change suggested by @Ryan, as well as upgrading sass-rails:

```
bundle update sass-rails
```

sass 3.2.6 worked for me, while 3.2.5 did not.

Answer (score 0):

We just had the same problem and fixed it by explicitly requiring sprockets in the Gemfile (even though it's a dependency of ActionPack):

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sprockets'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  # ...
end
```

I don't know why, but it works now. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head against this for days. The only solution that worked for me was as follows:

1. Make sure sass-rails to your :development group in your Gemfile.
2. If that doesn't fix it, add the following to a new file in config/initializers/ called something like "horrible_sass_patch.rb":

   ```
   begin
     require 'sass-rails'
   rescue
   end

   if Class.const_defined? "Sass::Script::Functions"
     module Sass::Script::Functions
       # This function exists, but doesn't automatically register
       declare :asset_url, [:value]
       declare :image_url, [:value]
       declare :font_url, [:value]
       # ... etc
     end
   end
   ```

Note: This requires that you are using the "active" Bundler loading mechanism, i.e. your application.rb uses the following:

```
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
```

... and if your stylesheets are in vendor, make sure they're included in Sass's configuration:

```
if config.respond_to? :sass
  config.sass.load_paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'stylesheets')
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add a trailing forward slash `/` to the path and use `url` like you usually do.

```
background-image: url("/assets/rails.png")
```