# How to correctly define asset paths in Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, asset-pipeline

Please excuse my noobness, I'm new to much of RoR.

I am having trouble getting my images to load when I deploy them to Heroku.

I have two images that load from a css file, which I moved to scss.

Initially I had

```
background: url(../images/k-opacity-70.png);

background: #111 url(../images/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
```

in a layout.css file

Then I noticed everything worked fine locally, but the images don't load when I deploy them to Heroku.

After some research and a multitude of different attempts, I now have

```
background: image-url('k-opacity-70.png');
background: #111  image-url('intro-bg.jpg')  no-repeat center;
```

in a file called layout.css.scss

Once again, the images work properly locally, but not when I deploy my app to Heroku.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My app is at blooming-coast-2140.herokuapp.com

----Update---
I've tried done the things seen in similar posts here and other websites with no luck...

```
gem ‘rails_12factor’, group: :production  

config.serve_static_assets = true
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = ‘X-Accel-Redirect’
config.assets.compile = true

heroku run rake assets:precompile

rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 0):

In your site CSS everything looks fine. Image is loaded properly. You are using file

```
http://blooming-coast-2140.herokuapp.com/assets/k-opacity-70-26821b89b8efd61bf304cc109d3af47e.png and this file exists
```

To make it work via image-url you should set up properly in your settings:

```
http_path = "../"
images_dir = "img"
relative_assets = true
```

Those are from my configuration from Compass. You should change them depending on your folders structure.

Comment: When you say settings is there a config file that I need to add that to?

Comment: Those are configs from Compass ( I use Compass together with SASS ). But it seems that in SASS it works the same way. Just look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304607/sass-rails-helpers-image-url-asset-url-are-not-working-in-rails-3-2-1

Comment: are you talking about the first answer?