# The Asset pipeline doesn't use the fingerprinted routes for the images after precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm loading the background image bg.jpg image in a SCSS file, ***style.css.scss***

```
background: url(/assets/bg.jpg)  no-repeat center center;
```

After precompilation, Sprockets places a copy of the image in the */public/assets* directory with a fingerprinted name *bg-28779d74f8a6fc51d1b46376428bed54.jpg* . And I also can access the image itself from the browser at the */assets/bg-28779d74f8a6fc51d1b46376428bed54.jpg* link.

But when I reaload the page in the browser, the background image is ***not*** displayed and when I check the CSS in Dev Tools for that particular element I see:

```
background: url(/assets/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

Shouldn't that be

```
background: url(/assets/bg-28779d74f8a6fc51d1b46376428bed54.jpg ) no-repeat center center;
```

LE: *I also precompile the assets with rake assets:precompile having the RAILS_ENV set to production. I thought it would be a good idea to mention this since I noticed many other people had problems because of this.*
[sass-rails helpers "image-url", "asset-url" are not working in rails 3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304607/sass-rails-helpers-image-url-asset-url-are-not-working-in-rails-3-2-1)

Comment: Did you *try* using the `asset-url()`/`image-url()` functions?  The question is specific to Rails 3.2, but you're using 4.

Comment: I've read somewhere that if the file is scss the url is enough for sprockets to know that it needs to change the image url. I tried it anyway and it still doesn't work.

Comment: On the other hand using ERB and `background: url(<%= asset_path 'bg.jpg' %>)  no-repeat center center;` seems to be working. ( _notice I had to remove the assets from the url link_). But I would prefer a solution that doesn't rely on ERB.

Comment: `background: image-url('bg.jpg')  no-repeat center center;` seems to work as well

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is already in the comments, but here it is:

Image URLs in your stylesheets (that point to images in the asset pipeline) should use the sass helper `image-url("bg.jpg")` instead of `url('/assets/bg.jpg')`

This helper uses the asset pipeline to find the correct path name for each image.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass